# Minimum Moves to Equal Array Elements

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

Given a non-empty integer array of size n, find the minimum number of moves required to make all array elements equal, where a move is incrementing n - 1 elements by 1.

Example:

Input:
[1,2,3]

Output:
3

Explanation:
Only three moves are needed (remember each move increments two elements):

[1,2,3]  =>  [2,3,3]  =>  [3,4,3]  =>  [4,4,4]
Discuss

I tried to brute force it, but I couldn't come with a correct algorithm, the loop invariants are incorrect. Would someone fix it with explanation so that I can improve my algorithms skills ?

```
bool checkEquality(vector<int> &num)
{

    for (int j = 1; j < num.size(); j++)
    {
        if (num[j] != num[j - 1])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


    int main() {

        vector<int> num = { 1, 2,3 };

        int numMoves = num.size() - 1;
        int prev = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while(!checkEquality(num))
        { 
            for (int i = prev; i < num.size(); i++)
            {
                for ( j = i; j < numMoves; j++)
                {
                    num[j]++;

                }
                if (i == num.size())
                {
                    prev = j;
                    j = 0;

                }
                else
                prev = 0;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: you code doesn't even produce an output...

Comment: I know, I want to fix the algorithm

Comment: why negating my question without even asking how to improve the question !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the problem as decreasing an element instead of increasing the others with one.

now the problem is a lot more simple.
you just need to add every element until it reaches the maximum element in the array.
I will solve it as below:

```
int findMax(vector<int> &num)
{
    int maximum=num[0];
    for(int i=1;i<num.size();i++)
    {
        if(maximum<num[i])
            maximum=num[i];
    }
    return maximum;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> num;
    num.push_back(1);
    num.push_back(2);
    num.push_back(3);

    int max_val=findMax(num);

    int answer=0;
    for(int i=0;i<num.size();i++)
    {
        answer+=max_val-num[i];
    }
    cout<<answer<<endl;

}
```

Comment: what's wrong with my solution? I want to increment each number, then check for equality. I want to fix my own algorithm

Comment: yes it's possible to increment each number but, it takes a lot more time and its almost very hard to explain it.

Comment: Would you fix it, and I will try to debug it ?

Comment: If we have n number of elements, we have to increment n-1 times and for every checking that we want to do!

Comment: the point of this problem is to see it from a different angle thats all

Comment: @NickyC just to practice the algorithm implementation

Answer (score 10):

Firstly, you don't need to do brute force for this problem. There is a linear time solution and the answer is

```
sum(num) - min(num) * length(num)
```

## Edit

#### Explanation

Incrementing all but one is equivalent to decrementing that one. So let's do that instead. How many single-element decrements to make all equal? No point to decrementing below the current minimum, so how many single-element decrements to make all equal to the current minimum? Just take the difference from what's currently there (the sum) to what we want (n times the minimum).

Here is the C++ code

```
int minMoves(vector<int>& nums) {
    if(nums.empty()) return 0;
    int n = nums.size();
    int sum = 0;
    int Min = INT_MAX;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        sum += nums[i];
        Min = min(Min, nums[i]);
    }
    return (sum - Min * n);
}
```

Or even in one line:

```
return accumulate(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 0) - nums.size() * *min_element(nums.begin(), nums.end());
```

Comment: what's wrong with my solution? I want to increment each number, then check for equality. I want to fix my own algorithm

Comment: You didn't event do the brute force in a way that could make sense. I didn't get what you intended to do in your code.

Comment: If you forcefully want to do brute force, You can calculate the maximum element and increment all element's value by 1 except the maximum value in each iteration and repeat until all elements are equal.

Comment: Wow... This is ridiculous. This is definitely the solution. I've been looking at this for 10 minutes and I still have no idea how it works

Comment: Does not work with `int[] nums = { 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1 }`, expected answer should be 5 and not 6.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way :

```
    int minMoves(vector<int>& nums) 
    {
         sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
         int moves=0, n=nums.size();                   
         for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
         {
            moves += (nums[n-1-i] - nums[0]);
         }
         return moves;  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way:-

```
int minMoves(vector<int>& nums) {
    int sum=0;
    int small= *min_element(nums.begin(),nums.end());
    for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++)
    {
        sum=sum+(nums[i]-small);
    }
    return sum;
}
```